# Sequelize - Best way to INSERT a long record

Tags: mysql, angular, sequelize.js

I have a table with 20 elements.

Is there a way to avoid this syntax :

```
Sequelize.create({
  elem1: req.body.eleme1,
  elem2: req.body.eleme2,
  elem3: req.body.eleme3,
  elem4: req.body.eleme4,
  elem5: req.body.eleme5,
  ..... 
  elem20: req.body.eleme20,
});
```

and do something like :

```
Sequelize.create({
  req.body
});
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a best way to do the same. One advice I can give you is to divide your tables into multiple table if columns are unrelated; *use normalization*

Then you can create associations or use transactions.
If this is not case and still you want to insert 20 records at a time.
A better way would be sanitize your data and create a wrapper separately then try to insert. 

Loop through your `req.body` and push them to the wrapper like below.

```
 const data = {}
    Object.keys(req.body).forEach(function(key, index) {
        data[key] = req.body[key]
    //you can perform any other operation on a particular property here
    })
Sequelize.create(data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I hadn't thought of doing that

Answer (score 0):

`Sequelize.create({...req.body})` should work as well, but if it's the only content, why not simply use `Sequelize.create(req.body)`?